# Background Sprite not always loading in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am using a scene manage.
I have only one activity and 7 Scenes classes extended from Scene.
What I do is a load all the resources to be used in the seven scenes only one in Main Activity and then I only switch the scene when required. The problem is that sometime background of any one of the seven scenes are not loaded and leaves a black screen.
Can any one tell me what problem is this???and what is the solution?
I am seeing this line in log cat I dont know if it is linked with my problem

```
 I/global(6383): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
```

Please provide me a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I seem to be having a similar problem.

Comment: no I haven't solved it yet. It depends of the device you are using. On devices with very low specs this problem occurs. Other wise its fine.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem, perhaps the solution is applicable here as well. When you create the Engine, try tweaking the options like this: engineOptions.getRenderOptions().disableExtensionVertexBufferObjects(); engine = new Engine(engineOptions);

Comment: I believe it forces the GPU memory to be constantly in sync with RAM.

Comment: I have tried but no luck. Noe instead of black the textures are white only.